# How To achieve multitenancy in aws quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, multi-tenant, amazon-quicksight, aws-sso

steps i am following

- I have first created an IAM user
- We have same user in default namespace
  aws quicksight register-user --namespace default --identity-type QUICKSIGHT --user-role ADMIN --region us-east-1 --email=jill@foocompany.com --user-name jill --aws-account-id 163

-created a custom namespace
aws quicksight create-namespace  --aws-account-id 163 --namespace FooCompanyNamespace --identity-store QUICKSIGHT

- registered a user with IAM on the custom namespace.
  aws quicksight register-user --namespace FooCompanyNamespace --identity-type QUICKSIGHT --user-role AUTHOR --region us-east-1 --email=jill@foocompany.com --user-name jill --aws-account-id 163

Afer registering this user in custom namespace - we are not able to access the quicksight using quicksight account name as - Custom namespace(FooCompanyNamespace). we are only able to login default namespace .

Main question?

1. Should IAM be different for each user? or IAM can be same for single user but for 2 name spaces
2. We are getting created message but we are not able to login custom namespace and when we check using CLI the user is registered.

We want to achieve multitenancy in aws quicksight such that there are two namespaces namespace1 and namespace2. We want that user1 can login to namespace1 with the access of admin and same user can login to namspace2 with reader access.Please suggest the correct way to achieve multitenancy.